# Wordpress: customize caption inside the fancybox slide with html elements

Tags: plugins, slideshow

I'm locally developing on *wordpress* version *6.4.3* a gallery page showing sculpture images. The theme is *twentytwentythree* and I'm using *Fancybox for wordpress* (version *3.3.4*) as a plugin for the gallery and slideshow.

Inside each picture of the gallery, there is a text with only the artwork name, such as

***This is the name of the sculpture***

Each image in the gallery should have a *title* attribute showing the artwork name plus other information, formatted this way:

Name of the sculpture\n\nYear: 2024\nSize (length x width x height): 25cm x 30cm x 40cm

when clicking on the image, the opened layer (which is a part of the slideshow) shows a bigger image with the caption inside that should be formatted as HTML and showing the same text of the title, such as:

***Name of the sculpture

Year: 2024
Size (length x width x height): 25cm x 30cm x 40cm***

(after *Name of the sculpture* there are two *<br>* tags and after *2024* there is one *<br>* tag)

I managed to get the only artwork name inside the image and the title attribute formatted with \n by placing inside each image the full text containing a special character **#** as a separator, such as

```
Name of the sculpture##Year: 2024#Size (length x width x height): 25cm x 30cm x 40cm
```

then included a javascript function in *Header and Footer* (as a part of plugin *WPCode*) which makes two things after loading the page:

- replaces the character # with \n to obtain the title attribute for each image in the gallery
- extracts from the full text the substring starting from the first character up to the character preceeding ## to obtain the artwork name inside each gallery image

The problem is the full text formatted as HTML inside each slide: I cannot find a way to replace # with *<br>* and have the caption properly formatted.

I looked into the plugin file fancybox.php and found a function named `mfbfw_init()` which has the following variable defined:

```
$caption = 'function( instance, item ) {var title ="";' .
           'if("undefined" != typeof jQuery(this).context ){var title = jQuery(this).context.title;} else { var title = ("undefined" != typeof jQuery(this).attr("title")) ? jQuery(this).attr("title") : false;}' .
           'var caption = jQuery(this).data(\'caption\') || \'\';' .
           'if ( item.type === \'image\' && title.length ) {' .                
           'caption = (caption.length ? caption + \'<br />\' : \'\') + \'<p class="caption-title">\'+title+\'</p>\' ;' .
           '}' .
           'return caption;' .
           '}';
```

I noticed that the `title` variable placed inside `<p class="caption-title">` and `</p>` is the the full text which appears with # as a caption inside each slide; if I could somehow replace

```
<p class="caption-title">\'+title+\'</p>
```

with

```
<p class="caption-title">\'+title.replace('\#\g', '<br />')+\'</p>
```

I'd get what I need, but unfortunately I cannot modify directly the fancybox.php as it will be overwritten on updates.

I also tried defining PHP code inside functions.php on a child theme, but nothing.

Hope I've been clear.

Thanks to anybody could give me helpful hints.